# Aspose.word :Add pdf attachment to word file

Tags: c#, .net, aspose.words

I am new to aspose.word  in .Net.

I have a template document where I need to replace text fields from a word document by the attachment.I have excel and pdf documents as attachments.

Can someday help me to add attachment to the word document?

Thanks,
Joy

Comment: Anything here can help you? http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to++Insert+a+Document+into+another+Document

Answer (score 0):

Once you've bound your data to the appropriate fields, convert it to a PDF. Then you can join the two PDFs together.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // save Aspose doc to stream as pdf
    doc.Save(ms, SaveFormat.Pdf);
    ms.Position = 0;

    // append doc
    var pdf = new PdfDocument(ms);
    pdf.Append(doc);
    pdf.Save(fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you please use [find and replace](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Find+and+Replace) feature of Aspose.Words to find a text and replace it with image and OLE object. You can insert an image into document using DocumentBuilder.InsertImage and insert an embedded or linked OLE object from a file into the document using DocumentBuilder.InsertOleObject method. Please refer to the following article.

[Use DocumentBuilder to Insert Document Elements](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Use+DocumentBuilder+to+Insert+Document+Elements)

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

you can use InsertOleObject

---

try this :

```
 doc = new Document();
    DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
    Stream memStream = File.OpenRead("addreess+file.xls");
    Shape oleObject = builder.InsertOleObject(memStream, "AcroExch.Document.7"", false, null);
```